# Power Automate - How can I update a SharePoint column when PowerApps form is submitted?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, powerapps-forms, automation

I have a Modern SharePoint list with a ton of columns, including a Status drop-down column.  The list form is a PowerApps form.  I want the Status column to populate "Submitted" when the user submits a form to the list.  I could do this easily with SP Designer, but I don't know the logic with Power Automate.  I created a "When a new item is created" Flow and populated the Site Address and List name.  I just don't know what the next step would be, or how to write it.  It's just the one column I need to change its status when a form is submitted.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, a very simple solution to this could be to set the `Default Value` for your Status column to "Submitted" in your SharePoint list.

However, if that won't meet your requirements, another option would be to use the Form.OnSuccess property to Patch the Status field.

In my example, my SharePoint list is called `List1`

```
    If(
    Self.Mode = 1,
    Patch(
        List1,
        Self.LastSubmit,
        {Status: {Value: "Submitted"}}
    )
)
```

In plain English, the formula checks if the form is in NewForm mode (Self.Mode=1) and if it is, patch the status column of the last submitted item to have a value of `Submitted`. If it's in Edit mode instead (Self.Mode=0), the Status won't be updated.

[image]